# Not getting program output in python IDLE

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python and currently have run the code below but I get no output in the IDLE. What's wrong?

```
import random

def getAnswer(answerNumber):
    if answerNumber == 1:
        return 'Its certain'
    elif answerNumber == 2:
        return 'It is decidedly so'
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        return 'Yes'
    elif answerNumber == 4:
        return 'Reply hazy try again'
    elif answerNumber == 5:
        return 'Ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 6:
        return 'Concentrate and ask again'
    elif answerNumber == 7:
        return 'My reply is no'
    elif answerNumber == 8:
        return 'Outlook not so good.'
    elif answerNumber == 9:
        return 'Very doubtful'

r = random.randint(1,9)
fortune = getAnswer(r)
print(fortune)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation, it seems that you have some indentation issue in the code snippet you have shared: you are calling `fortune = getAnswer(r)` within the function `getAnswer`

Comment: There's in indentation issue, and a typo "answerNuumber". Other than that the code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will be fine if you correct the `typo` and `indentation` as they mentioned in comments.
Corrected code

```
import random

def getAnswer(answerNumber):
    if answerNumber == 1:
        return 'Its certain'
    elif answerNumber == 2:
        return 'It is decidedly so'
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        return 'Yes'
    elif answerNumber == 4:
        return 'Reply hazy try again'
    elif answerNumber == 5:
        return 'Ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 6:
        return 'Concentrate and ask again'
    elif answerNumber == 7:
        return 'My reply is no'
    elif answerNumber == 8:
        return 'Outlook not so good.'
    elif answerNumber == 9:
        return 'Very doubtful'

r = random.randint(1,9)
fortune = getAnswer(r)
print(fortune)
```